# Knowing/converting AREA, PERIMETER units in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, area, units, convex-hull

I use Convexhull tool in QGIS and there are result value :

AREA = 0.0017494390 PERIMETER = 0.1725495172

I thought the result was strange. So, I took a rough estimate of the points through the services provided by other websites and picked out the results.

Other site result :
Area = 17220976.88 m^2 PERIMETER = 17030.657 m

Area value is a difference of 10^10
Perimeter value is a difference of 10^5..

I use "EPSG:4166 - Korean 1995" CRS and I also change project properties for units of distance, area. but, there are not any change.

So, I want to know what convex hull units are in QGIS and how to set other setting for ideal value.

Answer (score 4):

The unit of [EPSG:4166 - Korean 1995](https://epsg.io/4166) CRS is decimal degree. You need to change the projection of your data to a CRS that uses meter unit. For example, you can use `WGS 84 / UTM Zone ##` projection with the correct zone number `##` in which your data is located in.

The workflow is like this:

- Change the projection of your data to a `WGS 84 / UTM Zone ##` with correct Zone number
- Use the output data from the first step to add new fields for area and perimeter, and calculate both area and perimeter.

Comment: I'd suggest [EPSG:5179 (Korea 2000 / Unified CS)](https://epsg.io/5179)